# hashed password not works with me

Tags: javascript, node.js, passwords

I don't know why this hash password code does not work.
I did install `bcrypt`, also, it should go to the line (`res.send("testing")`)if the passwords are the same but anyway in all situations password does not match is coming even they are the same.

Here is my code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_host,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_user,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_password,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
});

exports.form = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  const { name, email, password, confirmPassword } = req.body;
  db.query(
    'SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?',
    [email],
    async (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      if (results.length > 0) {
        return res.render('form', {
          message: 'that email is already in use',
        });
      } else if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        return res.render('form', {
          message: 'passwords not match',
        });
      }

      let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash('password', 8);
      console.log(hashedPassword);
      res.send('testing');
    }
  );
};
``

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToNvN.png

and always (passwords not match) comes even as u see in pic the passwords are same
```

Comment: You're just saying it doesn't work but what exactly is the error and what are you expecting. Ask in more detail.

Comment: 1- hashed password should showed up in my console when i log in by correct equal passwords , but actually the else if (pass !== confirm pass ) condition comes even the passwords are same then the hashed not working after that the res.send not works also, i hope its clear now

Comment: please check the post after edite

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `bcrypt.hash()` you will get a different hash string, even with the same password, this is because the hashes are salted.

To check whether the hashes are equal, you need to test with `bcrypt.compare()`, you cannot compare to hashes directly. Some libraries also call it `bcrypt.verify()`.

Edit: Assuming you use the [node.bcrypt.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) library:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
let hashToStoreInDb = bcrypt.hashSync('mypassword', 10);

// Check if the entered login password matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from existingHashFromDb.
let existingHashFromDb = hashToStoreInDb;
const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync('mypassword', existingHashFromDb);
```

Comment: const salt=await bcrypt.genSalt(2)
    const hashdPassword=  await bcrypt.hash(password,salt);                                             async function compareIt(password){
    const validPassword=await bcrypt.compare(password,hashdPassword);
}

Comment: i try this but nothing happened, if u can clear to me or write on my code

Comment: @HAJ - Added an example. I used the sync methods for simplicity, of course you can switch to the async methods.